# Django ORM And Multiple Dynamic Databases

Tags: python, mysql, django, postgresql

Disclaimer: I am still pretty new to Django and am no veteran.

I am in the midst of building the "next generation" of a software package I built 10 years ago. The original software was built using CodeIgniter and the LAMP stack. The current software still works great, but it's just time to move on. The tech is now old. I have been looking at Django to write the new software in, but I have concerns using the ORM and the models file getting out of control.

So here's my situation, each client must have their own database. No exceptions due to data confidentiality and contracts. Each database mainly stores weather forecast data. There is a skeleton database that is currently used to setup a client. This skeleton does have tables that are common across all clients. What I am concerned about are the forecast data tables I have to dynamically create. Each forecast table is unique and different with the exception of the first four columns in the table being used for referencing/indexing and letting you know when the data was added. The rest of the columns are forecast values in a real/float datatype. There could be anything from 12 forecast data columns to over 365. Between all clients, there are hundreds of different/unique forecast tables.

I am trying to wrap my head around how I can use the ORM without having hundreds of methods in model.py. Even if I made a subdirectory and then a "model.py" for each client, I'd still have tons of model methods to deal with.

I have been reading up on how the ORM works for Django, but I haven't found anything (yet) out there that helps with my kind of situation. It's not the norm.

Without getting any more long winded about this, should I skip the ORM because of all these complexities or is there some stable way to deal with this besides going with SQL queries and stored procedures to get some performance gains?

Things to note: I did thorough benchmarking between MySQL and Postgres and will be using Postgres for the new project. I did test the option of using an array column vs having a column for each forecast value in Postgres hoping this would help with the potential modeling bloat issue. To my surprise, having a column for each forecast value provided faster querying than storing everything in an array column. So array storage is not a viable option for my data.

Comment: Have you looked into the JSON field provided by Postgres? It is also queryable with the [django ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#querying-jsonfield).

Comment: Hi @ViggieSmalls, I didn't bench against the JSON datatype because I figured the compression/performance would be worse compared to the array datatype. I might have to give it a try this weekend.

Comment: How many rows?.

Comment: Stored Procedures are unlikely to speed up anything -- but could help with your multitude of tables.

Comment: Hi @RickJames, I am benching against 1 billion rows with 1 date column, 3 smallint columns for indexing, and 108 real/float columns.

Comment: Most tables currently do not get to this size except for a handful of clients. It's more of a worst case scenario. The columns dynamically change per table based upon the forecast that is requested by the client.

Comment: @Gwi7d31 - That sounds like a terabyte of data for that one table.  Would you care to share some typical `SELECTs`?

Comment: Hi @RickJames, in a flat file, it is roughly 875GB. When run through Postgres, tables and indexes equate to ~541GB. I will see what I can do for you about the queries.

Comment: Hi @RickJames, I discovered that I accidentally screwed up my benchmark for real[] and I will be using real[] to cut down on datatype columns and give the ORM a fighting chance with a dynamic model.